# TYPO3 7.6.15 cannot define rooth path for a custom partial

Tags: typo3, fluid

I created contact form in TYPO3 7.6.15 using standard form extension. I also created custom partial for it, and I defined it inside of my root template setup:

```
plugin.tx_form {
  partialRootPaths {
    20 = fileadmin/templates/ext/form/partials
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I am not sure why. I saw that the form extension for this TYPO3 version is still in beta phase...

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Denis

Answer (score 1):

In the TYPO3 object browser, the paths to templates, layouts and partials are located in the object "view". So please try this:

```
plugin.tx_form {
    view {
        partialRootPaths.20 = fileadmin/templates/ext/form/partials/
    }
}
```